# Is there a way to change the theme according to the time

Tags: themes, mac, 19.10

I want my system to look like MacOS Mojave but I just can't change the

wallpaper and my theme according to the time of the day.

Is there a possibility to do that?

- I added the theme with gnome tweaks

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you considered the steps set out in this resource? https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=276689

Comment: How about https://github.com/C2N14/AutomaThemely/releases ?  @Graham too old ;-) I saw that one  too but the page I found also suggested the link for 18.04+

Comment: Try Wallch - https://launchpad.net/wallpaper-changer, there are some other options at: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/07/4-wallpaper-changer-ubuntu-18-04/

Comment: I want to use python to do so i will update and opensource the code as soon as posible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution:

- i made it with python

Github link: https://github.com/bigboy32/MacOSmojave

Have fun